# Can I configure Postman to sent Authorization header only if challenged by 401?

Tags: http, authorization, postman

I'm trying to set up tests in Postman to emulate my production software client. In the logs I can see that every client request is paired - a 401 followed by a 200. Evidently, the software client attempts anonymous access, and then sends the request again with the Authorization header once challenged.

I'd like to set Postman up the same way however I am seeing that Postman sends the Authorization header even if the server is configured to allow anonymous access. Is it possible to configure Postman to only send the Authorization header if challenged with 401?